# Interaction with shell through Ruby continuously?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to capture output from shell commands so I am using

```
response = `#{command}`
```

which is fine if you want to run only one command and not a continuous interaction. For instance if I do

```
response = `cd tmp`
# response = '', which is correct
response = `ls`
```

I would like it to return ls for within tmp, since in the previous command I had changed directory to temp. Is there a way to run a continuous shell on its own Thread or a gem or something to that effect?

Comment: I don't think doing `cd tmp ; ls ` works - maybe it tries going to the directory `tmp ; ls `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ` starts a sub-shell, so it does not affect your current Ruby shell. However you can use Ruby's `Dir.chdir` or `FileUtils.cd` to change the working directory of your Ruby shell.

Btw, maybe you like [fresh](https://github.com/janlelis/fresh), which is a hybrid between a system and a Ruby shell. You can normally use cd/ls there, while being in a Ruby shell.